# Figure text in R was suddenly turned to italic

Tags: r, figure

I've got a problem with the text in R figure.
my code is

```
    library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x = class, y = Proportion)) +
geom_point(aes(color = class)) +
scale_color_viridis_d() +theme_minimal()+
theme(text=element_text(size=16,face = "plain"))
```

However, the text in the figure is italic. I add the "face = "plain",
but it didn't work.
I don't know what is the reason,
I will appreciate an answer.

Comment: Try `face = "bold"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes, the face = "bold" works, but I need regular text.

Answer (score 0):

face argument have 4 options: plain, italic, bold & bold.italic.
If you don't want the figure is italic, you can remove face argument in element_text or you another value "bold".

Comment: Thank you, Yes, I removed face argument in element_text, but It is still "italic" when I change to bold, it becomes to "bold". only plain doesn't work, but I need "plain" text.

Answer (score 0):

class  `class(df$class)` may suppose to be a factor?

```
 mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
    library("ggplot2")
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y =mpg)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = cyl)) +
      scale_color_viridis_d() +theme_minimal()+
      theme(text=element_text(size=16,face = "plain"))
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes, the class(df$class) is a factor.